# Query bson files using python

Tags: python, mongodb, bson

I have a bson file: `xyz.bson` full of useful data and I'd like to query/process the data using python.  Is there a simple example/tutorial out there I can get started with?

I don't understand [this one](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `mongorestore` command to import the data into a mongoDB server and then query it by connecting to that server.

Comment: the documentation says its for json or csv.  does it work with bson?  http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoimport/

Comment: My bad. Yes, it must be `mongorestore` then. That reads .bson files.

Comment: looks like that's the one.  i'm a little confused on usage.  I have a file on my desktop `property.bson` and I tried `>mongostore --db propertyInfo /Desktop/property.bson` and got `SytaxError: Unexpected identifier`.  Can you point me to some good examples?

Comment: The command is `mongorestore`, in your example you wrote `mongostore`, maybe that is the reason.  You may also have to specify both a database name and a collection name to import to, using the `-d` and `-c` options (`-d` is equivalent to `--db`).  You also have an absolute pathname in your example, which may or may not be what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stream the data as though it were a flat JSON file on disk rather than loading it into a mongod, you can use this small python-bson-streaming library:

https://github.com/bauman/python-bson-streaming

```
from bsonstream import KeyValueBSONInput
from sys import argv
for file in argv[1:]:
    f = open(file, 'rb')
    stream = KeyValueBSONInput(fh=f,  fast_string_prematch="somthing") #remove fast string match if not needed
    for id, dict_data in stream:
        if id:
         ...process dict_data...
```

Comment: That Looks like a very interesting approach for querying The Exportes data

Answer (score 0):

You may use [sonq](https://github.com/socrateslee/sonq) to query .bson file directly from bash, or you can import and use the lib in Python.

A few examples:

- Query a .bson file

  `sonq -f '{"name": "Stark"}' source.bson`
- Convert query results to a newline separated .json file

  `sonq -f '{"name": {"$ne": "Stark"}}' -o target.json source.bson`
- Query a .bson file in python

  `from sonq.operation import query_son
  record_list = list(query_son('source.bson', filters={"name": {"$in": ["Stark"]}}))`